# Yii rights issue on multiuser login

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-modules

How to create yii rights menu for two different user logins where they have separate roles and permissions for them .In brief yii rights module to be created separately for two different user logins.

I have created an application where every individual group of users must have a role created for them. Say for example there is a group such as joy they should have separate rights extension and another group fun those users must have separate rights extension to them

Comment: this is a poorly constructed question. Please take the time to show what you have done, provide code if possible, and show what is working and what is not.

Comment: i have create an application where every individual group of users must have a role created for them.say for example there is a group such as joy they should have separate rights extension and another group fun those users must have separate rights extension to them

Comment: it is a saas based hrm consultancy application where rights for users differes based on their consultancy id

Comment: help me with answer as soon as possible